# speeding up recursive query/ looping through values

Tags: sql, db2, recursive-query

Suppose table with structure like this:

```
create table tab1
(
id int,
valid_from timestamp
)
```

I need to build query such that in case there is a duplicity over pair (id,valid_from), e.g.

```
id    valid_from
1     2000-01-01 12:00:00
1     2000-01-01 12:00:00
```

then one second needs to be added to subsequent rows to valid_from column. 
For example if there are three duplicate rows, the result should be as follows

```
id    valid_from
1     2000-01-01 12:00:00
1     2000-01-01 12:00:01
1     2000-01-01 12:00:02
```

Tried running a recursive cte query but since for some cases there is a large number of duplicate values (for current data set about 160 for some cases of (id,valid_from)), it is really slow.
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe without seeing your actual table and index definitions, your exact query, and the query execution plan it will be possible to give you any meaningful advice.

Comment: What if you have `2000-01-01 12:00:00`, `2000-01-01 12:00:00`, `2000-01-01 12:00:01`?

Comment: Third value is completely different over pair(id,valid_from) and nothing should be done with it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "next second" is not occupied, then:

```
WITH TAB (id, valid_from) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:00'))
, (1, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:00'))
, (1, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:00'))

, (2, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:00'))
, (2, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:01'))
, (2, TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 12:00:01'))
)
SELECT ID, VALID_FROM
, VALID_FROM + (ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, VALID_FROM) - 1) SECOND AS VALID_FROM2
FROM TAB
ORDER BY ID, VALID_FROM2;
```

The result is:

```
|ID         |VALID_FROM                |VALID_FROM2               |
|-----------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|1          |2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|
|1          |2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.01.000000|
|1          |2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.02.000000|
|2          |2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.00.000000|
|2          |2000-01-01-12.00.01.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.01.000000|
|2          |2000-01-01-12.00.01.000000|2000-01-01-12.00.02.000000|
```

Comment: thanks, tried to overkill it with cte recursion but seems solution is pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select id,
       valid_from + (row_number() over (partition by id order by valid_from) - 1) second
from t;
```